# From which well-known mathematician is this theorem on spectral radius come from?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, normed-spaces, math-history

Here is the statement :

> Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then for any submultiplicative matrix norm $N$ (induced or not) we have : $\rho(A) \le N(A)$, where $\rho$ is the spectral radius of $A$.

So from which well-known mathematicians this little result come from ? According to several references, it could be Browne or Hirsch but it is not clear...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Presumably you are including the submultiplicative property $\|AB\| \le \|A\| \|B\|$ in the definition of "matrix norm". This is not always done, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Comment: This inequality as well as $\rho(A)\le\|A^k\|^{1/k}$ are the easy ones. It is possible that their discoverers weren't well-known mathematicians. On the other hand, the truly non-trivial one, Gelfand's formula, was discovered independently by Beurling in 1938 and by Gelfand in 1941.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Indeed thank you for the precision !

Comment: @user1551 ok I remembered that I have already the name of Beurling somewhere !